# Existence of a continuous map from $\Bbb{R}$ to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Let $S^1$ be the unit circle $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$. Does there exist a continuous map $f$ from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $f(\Bbb{R})=S^1$?

I only know that $|S^1|=|\Bbb{R}|$ due to the existence of a bijection between these two sets and a non-compact set $\Bbb{R}$ may have a compact image like $S^1$ but not able to find such $f$.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: It is difficult to believe you got to a point where you know what a compact set is but cannot parametrize a circle :-)

Comment: I regret for that..@MSA..thanks for this valuable comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example

$f(x) = (\cos x, \sin x).$

Comment: ..thanks..now I regret for what I asked.